# Литералы в Python

Tags: python, литерал

Объясните, пожалуйста, про литералы в Python, есть ли какие-то статьи или подобная информация по этой теме?

Comment: Литерал (literal) - переводится примерно как "буквально" или "буквальный". Буквально строка, буквально число, буквально байтовая строка, т.е. записанные прямо в коде. А не строка, число или байтовая строка из переменной, например.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему некоторые минусуют этот вопрос. По моему это очень хороший вопрос, я тоже имел в этом путаницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда я впервые с этим встретился, тоже не понимал, почему такой чудесный и излишний термин — почему `13` *не просто число*, а **литерал**. :-)

Основание для такого термина *чисто теоретическое*, чтобы возможно было одним словом выразить несколько подобных вещей.

**Литерал** — это ни переменная, ни значение переменной, а **запись** какого-то

- **конкретного** числа (целого, реального или мнимого),
- **конкретной** строки, или
- **конкретной** байтовой строки.

Литерал относится к синтаксису, т.е. к форме записы.

---

*Примеры литералов:*

- **числа**:   `7`, `-3.14`, `2.3е-8` (экспоненциальна форма), `0b10110100` (двоичная форма), `0x1AF2`(шестнадцатеричная форма), `5j` (мнимое число).
- **строки**:   `'Маша'`, `f'Тебе {years} лет.\n'` (f-строка), `r'^[AaXx]+\d\.'` (сырая строка).
- **байтовые строки**:   `b'\x30\xc1'`, `b'Ivan'` (невозможно использовать русские буквы).

---

См. оригинальную документацию на английском [The Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/), часть [2.4. Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).

---

*Примечание:*

Хотя в русских текстах вы можете встретиться с терминами как **«булевой литерал»**, **«списковый литерал»** и тд., в официальной документации таких литералов нет. `True` и `False` не литералы, **а ключевые слова**, а хотя списки могут состоять только из литералов, они не литералы.

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо огромное. Т.е. , как понимаю, литерал - это какое-то значение переменной. И, получается, что вместо строкового литерала можно говорить строка, вместо литерала с плавающей точкой можно говорить число с плавающей точкой, вместо целочисленного литерала говорить целое число и это вс будет правильно?Очень это понятие путает. Впервые с ним столкнулась в книге «Начинаем программировать на Python. 5-е изд.» Автор: Тони Гэддис.

Comment: Да и нет.;-) Значение переменной **не** литерал, а просто число. Литералом оно будет только тогда, когда оно будет **написано**. В присвоении `а = 2` после знака `=` находится литерал `2`, но в переменной `a` будет целое число `2`. Литерал — это синтаксис; интерпретатор Питона из его формы знает (и должен знать), что это целое число, а не другой тип числа или строка. - Но вы (предполагаю) не интерпретатор Питона, а человек; потому вы можете забыть об литералах и говорить просто «число», «строка», и т.д. (Я тоже человек и тоже так говорю. ;-))

Comment: Между прочим, ваш вопрос в комментарии был таким хорошим, что я благодаря ему улучшил мой ответ. Спасибо вам!

Comment: Пытаюсь разобраться, возникает очень много вопросов))))У Т.Гэддис написано: "В терминах программирования цепочка символов, которая используется в качестве данных, называется символьной последовательностью, или строковым значением, или просто строкой.Когда символьная последовательность появляется в рабочем коде программы, она называется строковым литералом."  Когда я посмотрела на эту запись я поняла, что строковый литерал и строка одно и то же.....

Comment: Ещё момент, неясно, как литералы связаны с пустыми скобками [], (), {}. С пустыми списками, кортежами, множествами?получается, что там конкретно пусто? А, вот, если пустая строка, её можно ли назвать строковым литералом? Если честно, у меня образовалась огромная каша с литералами, но очень хочется разобраться. Я вот сижу сейчас и всё равно не могу переосмыслить почему строковый литерал нельзя назвать строкой...Теперь образоваваются вопрос: а правильно ли я вообще понимаю, что представляет собой строка в Пайтон.....

Comment: И ещё момент: как можно ещё назвать литералы в Пайтон, по-другому, но чтобы было понятно, что это литералы, без упоминания таких страшных формулировок? Например, если не хочу использовать слово "литерал" у себя в презентациях, но назвать коротко так, не коверкая их основной смысл.

Comment: Товарищи, зашла на курсы степика по ссылке: https://stepik.org/lesson/265115/step/1             У них написано: "Для создания строковой переменной (литерала), мы должны заключить необходимый текст в кавычки. В Python можно использовать как одинарные кавычки, так и двойные:"....Т.е. в степике строковую переменную приравнивают к литералу....это, как?

Comment: @PYTHON_KA **Не читайте другие тексты о литералах, в моем ответе все в соответствии с оригинальной документацией.** Я вас уже в примечании в конце моего ответа предупредил, что вы можете встретиться с неправильными использованиями термина «литерал» и что нет списковых, множественных, кортежных и тд. литералов (т.е. никаких «пустых» литералов связанных со скобками [], (), {}. Да, **пустая строка в форме  `""` или `""""""` или `''` или `''''''` — это литерал.**

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь. Очень много дезинформирующей информации кругом, да. Вчера даже сталкивалась с видео на ютубе, как парень уверенно заявил,  что литерал - это текст, который взят в одинарные кавычки.)))) Буду опираться на Вашу статью. Скажите, а вот Т.Гэддис Вы не читали? Все эту книгу рекомендуют, я её тоже сейчас изучаю. беру оттуда информацию. А, точно, сегодня про принятие ответа забыла)Спасибо, что напомнили мне!!!!

Comment: А, поняла, в строковом литерале - это запись, которая берётся во внимание с кавычками, а без кавычек -это будет значение переменной. Только дошло сейчас! Надеюсь, что этот момент поняла правильно)))

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста,за буквоедство. Подскажите пожалуйста, а как правильно читать слово литерал. Произношу, как вижу, но, возможно, я ошибаюсь.)))